# Events in java script

Tags: javascript, dom

Хотел узнать как можно сделать следующее:

Надо чтобы при выборе одной из опций, отсылало на форму этой опции, 
в то же время убирая другие формы.

Данный код JavaScript не работает. Почему ?

Буду рад если кто поможет с кодом, как можно его модифицировать и укоротить для получения такого же результата.

```js
document.getElementById("createcompany").onselect = function() {
    document.getElementById("create_company_form").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("remove_company_form").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("update_company_form").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("get_company_with_id_form").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("getallcompanies_form").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("create_customer_form").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("remove_customer_form_byid").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("remove_customer_form_byname").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("update_customer_form").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("get_cust_with_id_form").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("getallcustomers_form").style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<select size = 11>
     <option disabled> Menu</option>
     <option id = "createcompany">Create company</option>
     <option id = "remove">Remove company</option>
     <option id = "update">Update company</option>  
     <option id = "get_company_with_id">Get company by id</option>
     <option id = "getallcompanies">Get all companies</option>
     <option id = "create_customer">Create customer</option>
     <option id = "remove_customer_by_id">Remove customer by id</option>
     <option id = "remove_customer_by_name">Remove customer by name</option>
     <option id = "update_customer">Update customer</option>  
     <option id = "get_cust_with_id">Get customer by id</option>
     <option id = "getallcustomers">Get all customers</option>  
 </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужное событие - не `select`, а `change`.

В атрибут `value` каждой опции записываем id формы, с которой опция ассоциируется:

```
<select size="11" id="operationSelector">
    <option disabled>Menu</option>
    <option id="createcompany" value="create_company_form">Create company</option>
    <option id="remove" value="remove_company_form">Remove company</option>
    ...
```

Каждой форме присваиваем класс `operationForm` (на всякий случай, вдруг на странице есть еще формы):

```
<form id="create_company_form" class="operationForm">...
```

Затем оформляем в скрипт (для всех опций и их форм):

```
operationSelector.onchange = function() {
    var forms = document.getElementsByClassName("operationForm")
    for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++)
        forms[i].style.display = "none" // скрываем все формы
    // и отображаем нужную
    document.getElementById(operationSelector.value).style.display = "block"
}
```

Comment: click тоже работать не будет. Точнее, будет, но не во всех браузерах.

Comment: @Qwertiy это где click не работает? http://htmlbook.ru/html/attr/onclick

Comment: @Qwertiy изменила на change, спасибо, так выглядит лучше

Comment: @naiad09 Пока не заинтересован в изучении Jquery.. 
По заданию просто надо пока ознакомится с Java script если так можно сказать "Обычной".. Если сможеш логику скрипта написать на JS, буду признателен.

Comment: @Maks.Burkov переписала

Comment: @naiad09 Не понял в конце.. Че там передаётся ? в метод который берет элементы по айди ..

Comment: "operationSelector.onchange" Что это ? Айди селектора ?

Comment: @Maks.Burkov для любого элемента формы атрибут `value` - значение, которое он хранит. для селектора - это значение, которое имеет выбранная в нем опция. поскольку в `value` опций указаны id форм, этот id и передается в getElementById. мы получаем нужный элемент формы.

Comment: это эквивалент `document.getElementById(...)` . к элементам, для которых задан id, можно так обращаться напрямую, без его поиска по документу. однако, в случае c `value` мы имеем только строку с id, а не сам элемент, поэтому ее необходимо обернуть в `document.getElementById(...)`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41031/discussion-between-naiad09-and-maks-burkov).

Comment: Спасибо все разобрался!

Answer (score 0):

1. `select` => `change`
2. Вешать не на `option`, а на `select`
3. `id` => `value`